# Find and replace in UNIX

Tags: sed

I'm having the following string in a file called `test.txt`,

```
test.log test1.log test2.log
```

I want to replace it with

```
test.log -A test1.log -A test2.log
```

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/.log/.log -A/g' test.txt
```

But the output is

```
test.log -A test1.log -A test2.log -A
```

I don't want that to be appended in the last file. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What have you done already? What is your problem in doing that?

Comment: I used the below command

Comment: sed -i 's/.log/.log -A/g' test.txt But the output is test.log -A test1.log -A test2.log -A I don't want that to be appended in the last file

Comment: @Pranav, , please review the help files on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to format a post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Answering questions in comments is fine, but something significant like code should be added to the posting by editing.

Comment: … but then, perhaps the system isn’t *letting* you edit … it certainly isn’t letting *me* edit, until the pending edit is approved … how annoying.

Comment: @TomZych you could choose to improve pending edit suggestions, reject and edit and so on..

Comment: @Sundeep Yes, but I arrived here from review, and had already approved the pending edit, so I was stuck. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: @TomZych oh, that's interesting.. may be put in a feature request ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arguments are separated by space and final argument in the line doesn't have spaces after it, you could use this:

```
$ cat ip.txt
test.log test1.log test2.log

$ sed 's/\.log /&-A /g' ip.txt
test.log -A test1.log -A test2.log
```

- since `.` is a metacharacter, you have to use `\.` to match it literally
- `&` in replacement section represents entire matched portion in search section

You could also use `awk` here, better suited for field processing and added advantage of stripping away whitespaces at start/end of line

```
$ awk -v OFS=' -A ' '/\.log/{$1=$1} 1' ip.txt
test.log -A test1.log -A test2.log
```

- default input field separator(FS) is one or more contiguous whitespace, so no need to set that
- `-v OFS=' -A '` set space followed by `-A` and space as output field separator(OFS)
- `/\.log/` if line contains `.log`

  - `$1=$1` re-build input record, so that input FS will be replaced by OFS
- `1` idiomatic way to print input record
- note that this solution won't change a line if it doesn't contain `.log`